# Calling an existing realm database in android?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have an existing database which I converted from CSV to .realm database. 
Now I need to call that in my Android project. 
I get issues around schema.

I have been able to reach upto the realm file but then it gives me the following error, that is something related with the model. and If I call deleteMigrationIfNeeded method in realm only then It runs with out error but in doing that I get empty db.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application android.search786.apkia.com.MyApplication: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: The 'AL_QURAN_TBL' class is missing from the schema for this Realm.
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error says what is wrong:

```
The 'AL_QURAN_TBL' class is missing from the schema for this Realm.
```

Apparently you have that table in your Realm file, but no corrosponding Java model class. Either add this class with the correct fields or a migration step that deletes it from the file.